# Scrapy, Xpath, extracting h3 content?

Tags: html, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to extract everything after **h3 class** AIRFRAME **/h3** but before **h3 class** ENGINES **/h3**:

What I need extracted:

"Entry Into Service: December 2010
Total Time Since New: 3,580 Hours" etc.

[HTML code photo - not sure how to embed it directly instead of having a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKYNh.png)

Below is what I've tried but it doesn't return anything. I'm new to Scrapy and programming in general so I would appreciate some help. I've tried searching through other posts and google in general without any luck.

input = response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_rejected']/h3/text()").extract()

output = []

Comment: Do **never** include code as image. Always copy it as text in a `code` section, because otherwise an attempt could not be reproduced and would be worthless for SO.

Comment: HINT: Check if the value of the @class attribute contains a line-break.

Comment: Thanks. This was my first post so I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you are using is referencing another class that doesn't have the text you mentioned.

```
input = response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_rejected']/h3/text()").extract()
```

The name of the class in the picture is `large-6 cell selectorgadget_selected` and not `large-6 cell selectorgadget_rejected`

Also, if you use `.../h3/text()` you are going to scrape the text inside the H3 tag.
As I understand you want the text after the H3, between the `<div>`. So try something like this:

```
input = response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_selected']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Thank you. Using your code above as a reference (I made a slight change) I was able to get an output of the content after the `<H3>` tag. The code is: `response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell']/text()").extract()` There are 4 different `<H3>` tags from which I need to get information, AIRFRAME being one of them. The 4 tags are part of the `large-6 cell` class and thus I get the results for all 4 in the same output. How would I change my code so that the output is only for AIRFRAME?

Comment: Hi @Arty, that's hard to answer without seeing the actual html. You can try something like this in the XPath: `//div[@class='large-6 cell']/h3[contains(text(), "AIRFRAME")]/parent::div/text()`. It will only find the H3 that contains the text inside the quotes `" "` and will return to the parent `<div>` for the text. - If my answer solved your issue, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @renatodvc's answer, you could add `normalize-space` function to ignore whitespace nodes.

```
//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_selected']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Or use the function directly on the element :

```
normalize-space(//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_selected'])
```

Output :

```
AIRFRAME " Entry Into Service: December 2010" " Total Time Since New: 3,58@ Hours" " Total Landings Since New: 1,173" " (as of September 2019)" " Program Coverage: Enrolled on Smart Parts Plus" " Maintenance Tracking: CAMP "
```

Then, to extract the values, you can use regex :

```
import re
text = 'AIRFRAME " Entry Into Service: December 2010" " Total Time Since New: 3,58@ Hours" " Total Landings Since New: 1,173" " (as of September 2019)" " Program Coverage: Enrolled on Smart Parts Plus" " Maintenance Tracking: CAMP "'
data = [el.strip() for el in re.findall(':(.+?)\"', text, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(data)
```

Output :

```
['December 2010', '3,58@ Hours', '1,173', 'Enrolled on Smart Parts Plus', 'CAMP']
```

Comment: Thanks! The `normalize-space` function doesn't seem to work. I tried the following code `response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell']/text()")[normalize-space()].extract()` and got the following error `name 'normalize' is not defined`

Comment: Your expression contains a typo. It should be : `response.xpath("//div[@class='large-6 cell selectorgadget_selected']/text()[normalize-space()]").get()`